# ¿Cómo hacer que case devuelva un mensaje si el campo es NULL?

Tags: sql-server, condiciones

Estoy realizando una `consulta` que de acuerdo a un campo `FK` me imprima un mensaje de acuerdo a lo que la `subconsulta` me arroje, en caso de que sea `NULL` quiero que me imprima "Sin promoción", caso contrario, que imprima el nombre de la promoción encontrada por la `subconsulta`. Ejemplo:

```
case
(select top(1) p.nombre from promociones p where cm.id_promocion = p.id_promocion)

    when null then 'Sin promoción'
    when (select top(1) p.nombre from promociones p where cm.id_promocion = p.id_promocion) then (select top(1) p.nombre from promociones p where cm.id_promocion = p.id_promocion) 

end as 'Promoción',
```

O con el `IIF`:

```
IIF((select top(1) p.nombre from promociones p where cm.id_promocion = p.id_promocion) = null, 'Sin promoción', (select top(1) p.nombre from promociones p where cm.id_promocion = p.id_promocion)) 'Promoción'
```

Pero ninguno de los dos me imprime el `Sin promoción`, también lo intenté con `''`, los dos me arrojan el nombre de la promoción correspondiente, pero los campos que tienen el campo `foráneo` vacío, o sea `NULL`, no me muestra dicho mensaje. ¿Qué puedo hacer para que me imprima ese mensaje cuando la `subconsulta` me arroje valores `NULL`?

Comment: ¿Y con `ISNULL((select top(1) p.nombre from promociones p where cm.id_promocion = p.id_promocion), 'Sin promoción')`? Por otro lado ¿por que una subconsulta a nivel de columna? si publicas el código completo, tal vez se te pueda sugerir una forma mejor.

Comment: De esa manera sí funcionó, muchas gracias